# Forwarding from one SOCKS proxy to another

Tags: socks

I want to set up a SOCKS proxy that listens on port 1080 and forwards data to another proxy listening on port 22 on 1.2.3.4. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [sockschain](http://www.ufasoft.com/socks/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any SOCKS-level access control on the first link, and only need TCP, you don't even need to use a SOCKS server on the first hop, just a TCP plug through to the second hop SOCKS server will do.